# How to group lines in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DO_PIECE
    , SUM(Tot_Impt)
FROM PAYMENT
GROUP BY DO_PIECE
    , TOT_Impt
```

My problem is that the result gives me the two lines below:

```
1 0.001
1 2.035
```

I want the result to be one line:

```
1 2.036
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `TOT_Impt` from your group by :

```
Select DO_PIECE, SUM(Tot_Impt) 
FROM PAYMENT Group By DO_PIECE
```

Other wise it will give you one row for each `DO_PIECE, Tot_Impt` combination, but you just want one row for each `DO_PIECE`.

Comment: and no need for the `DISTINCT`

Comment: @Lamak Ooops yes!